# My Project Templates Are Missing With Version-less FDT

Tags: flash, fdt

I just upgraded to FDT (new subscription model), got everything working, then went to create a new project with a custom template - gone!
Found the folder had been moved to projectTemplateBackup, moved it back into projectTemplates... but it still doesn't show up in the New Project Wizard.
What gives? Has this feature been removed?

Answer (score 0):

The feature has not been removed.

The internal version of the templates has changed since 
we fix a few bugs and add new small features inside the templates and templates handling.
The version is now 2.6

Old templates with version less than 2.6 are hidden to minimize disturbance to 
standard users by old incorrect or not working templates.

You can increase the version number of your template and copy 
them to the projectTemplates folder and they should work again.